# Truth table from text file to a 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/zgUef181

table.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "table.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


Table::Table(){
   userFile = "";
   tableArray[0][0];
   height = 0;
   width = 0;
   n = 0;
}

Table::~Table(){
   // cout<<"Object terminated...forevurrrr"<<endl;
}

void Table::readInFile(){
   cout<<"Reading file..."<<endl;
   ifstream readme(userFile.c_str());
   string line;
   int countRow= 0; //this count = the row in the array
   while(getline(readme, line)){
      if(countRow == 0){
         n = atoi(line.c_str());
         countRow++;
      }
      else{
         for(int i = 0; i < line.length();++i){
            if(line[i]=='0'){
               tableArray[countRow-1][i]=0;
               cout << tableArray[countRow-1][i] << " ";
            }
            else if(line[i]=='1'){
               tableArray[countRow-1][i]=1;
               cout << tableArray[countRow-1][i] << " ";
            }
            else{

            }
         }

         if(countRow == height){
            cout<<"line: " << line[line.length()-1] << endl;
            //int wtf = line[line.length()-1];
            //cout << "wtf: " << wtf;
         }
         else{
            cout<<"line: " << line[line.length()-2] << endl;
         }
         countRow++;
      }
   }
   Table::printArray(tableArray, height, width);

}

void Table::getFileName(){
   cout << "Enter file name pls: " << endl;
   cin >> userFile;
   if(checkIfExists(userFile)!=true){
      cout << "Nope, couldn't find the file. Try again." << endl;
      Table::getFileName();
   }
   else{
      Table::collectInfo();
      Table::readInFile();
   }
}

//check if the file exists
bool Table::checkIfExists(string file_path){
   cout<<"Gotta check if this exists..."<<endl;
   bool real_file=0;
   ifstream mystream(file_path.c_str());
   string line;
   try{
      while(getline(mystream, line)){
         real_file=1;
      }
      cout<<"Found da booty"<<endl;
   }
   catch(int e){
      cout<<"we got an error bruh"<<endl;
   }
   mystream.close();
   return real_file;

}

void Table::collectInfo(){
   cout<<"collectInfo"<<endl;
   ifstream readme(userFile.c_str());
   string line;
   string leHeight;

   getline(readme, leHeight);
   height = atoi(leHeight.c_str());
   height = pow(2,height);
   cout<<height<<endl;


   while(getline(readme, line)){
      width = line.length();
   }
   width = (width + 1) / 2;
   cout<<width<<endl;
   int** tempTable = new int*[width];

   for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
      tempTable[i] = new int[width];
   }
   tableArray = tempTable;
}

void Table::printArray(int** array, int h, int w){
   cout<<"printArray"<<endl;
   //string line;

   for(int i = 0; i < h; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < w; j++){
         cout << array[i][j];
         if(j==(w-1))
            cout << endl;


         // if(array[i][j]==1){
         //      line.append("1 ");
         // }
         // else if(array[i][j]==0){
         //      line.append("0 ");
         // }
         // else{
         //      line.append("error");
         // }
      }
      //cout<<line<<endl;
      //line="";
   }

}
```

table.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
#ifndef TABLETOBOOL
#define TABLETOBOOL

class Table{
   private:
      string userFile;
      int** tableArray;
      int numOfRow;
      int numOfCol;
      int height;
      int width;
      int n;
   public:
      Table();
      ~Table();

      void printArray(int**,int,int);
      void readInFile();
      void getFileName();
      bool checkIfExists(string file_path);
      void collectInfo();

};

#endif
```

tableMain.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "table.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Table runTable;
   runTable.getFileName();

   return 0;
}
```

//sample2.txt

```
4
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

It has the implementation file, header file, main, and sample text to input into the program.

The first line of the sample text is the number of inputs, so 2^n (n being number of inputs) is the number of lines in the truth table. So far, I can read in the file then output it correctly, but it doesn't look like it is actually saving to the array for some reason.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/ffded2e471054da83bd1ee1370a49a7e.png) of the execution. After the "Reading file..." is the truth table printed out in the readInFile function. The "Line: " part shows you the output, either a 1 or 0, which is the last number on each line. This is important, because the lines that have output of 0 can be omitted as I am ultimately trying to create a simplified boolean expression. What I'd like to do, is use an if statement like "if (line[line.length()-1]==0){ //skip line in the file}". I tried this and it wasn't working and I have no idea why.

When I go to print the array, it prints out a bunch of what I can only assume to be memory addresses? I'm not really sure.

Thanks for the help in advance. All the best

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the flow of code?

Comment: Allocation is wrong, you don't skip spaces in input so you get random garbage in memory etc

Answer (score 0):

One issue with this code is that you never allocate memory for `TableArray` before you start writing to it.  If you know `width` and `height` in advance, you could declare your storage as a `std::vector`.

Another problem is that the code to calculate width per line is really odd and fragile.  A vector would let you just `push_back` hints until you run out.

Comment: Okay, `collectInfo()` tries to do this, but are you sure it’s reading the right file?  You never pass the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix all your problems, but ...

You are not allocating enough memory for `tempTable`. You have:

```
int** tempTable = new int*[width];
```

but it should be:

```
int** tempTable = new int*[height];
```